# Move files across apfs volumes in the same container

Tags: macos, apfs

To prevent data loss from accidental deletion of files, I use Carbon Copy Cloner to make snapshots on my system volume. I just realised that for things like VM and tmp files it's a better idea to put them into a seperate volume that have seperate snapshot policies. However, my VMs are quite large (50GB~100GB), and I'm wondering if there is any more efficient way to move them to another volume than to copy using cp/Finder. In theory, it is still on the same filesystem, but I don't know of any way to move files to another volume by only changing the filesystem metadata.